# Using http calls outside of offchain worker context

Tags: pallet, offchain-worker, substrate-node

Is it possible make http requests outside of an `offchain worker` context. It seems like the only thing that is preventing http calls is simply that `OffchainWorkerExt` is not registered in the runtime. I'm thinking it could be possible to make a separate `Ext` that only has the ability to make http request or possibly add the `OffchainWorkerExt` into the substrate Runtime environment to allow for http calls.

We are aware of the fact that making network requests inside of the Substrate runtime on chain is typically ill-advised, but have a plan in place to manage this system.

The only other solution to this would be to have a system of relays that post submit data on chain and that would need to be verified on addition. This solution has the issue that gas costs would be increasing over time and eventually discourage relayers to submit blocks to our node.